# Простой плагин Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, есть ли ресурс с простой документацией разработки плагинов под CMS Wordpress. Очень давно уже не касался PHP, и в официальной документации всё не особо понятно.
Не могу найти информацию, чтобы плагин был без создания кастомного типа post, как везде описывают. Мне надо сделать чтобы в плагине было три сущности (Категория, Номенклатура, Город). Но как реализовать, что то не пойму, чтобы без костылей. Просмотрел не мало видеоуроков, делают кастомный тип post, категории используют таксономии (но в этом случае кастомный post можно привязать к нескольким категориям, а мне нужно только к одной). Т.е. по факту получается клон блоговых записей, мне так не надо.

Comment: Просто при регистрации таксономии укажите, что она привязана к post. Custom post type для этого регистрировать не надо

Comment: Так мне post вообще не нужен. Мне нужна своя сущность. Как с этим быть?

Comment: register_post_type, register_taxonomy( 'your-post-type', ... )

Comment: Хорошо, а в таксономию можно поле своё добавить?

Comment: К таксономии нет, а к термину можно добавить метабокс. Загуглите, там 2-3 хука нужно

Comment: кастомый тип контента и будет "твоя сущность".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, из того что рекомендовали, ничего в моём случае не подошло. Особо времени разбираться не было, по этому пошёл по следующему пути:
1. Создал кастомные таблицы в базе данных.
2. С помощью сервиса (http://projects.tareq.co/wp-generator/index.php) сгенерировал все необходимые файлы для построения простого CRUD админ интерфейса. Вот видеоинструкция пользования сервиса (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrFViVnGY68). Сервис правда в течении двух дней пока с ним работал, немного менялся, скорее автор его ещё допиливает.
3. Подредактировал код для кашерного вывода записей и связки разных таблиц.
4. Закастылил функцию удаления записей, ибо она не работала. На странице с видеоинструкцией оставил коментарий с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот лучший плагин в мире https://github.com/mihdan/cyr2lat. Изучайте его, там собраны лучшие практики по WordPress. И задавайте более конкретные вопросы.